# GBQ SQL: Counting instances of specific fields/rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this table:

```
Field1   Field2
01       A
01       B
02       C
03       D
04       D
```

I need to find 2 different types of scenarios.

- Scenario 1: Find rows where value in Field 1 is assigned to more than 1 value in Field 2.
- Scenario 2 (vise versa): Find rows where value in Field 2 is assigned to more than 1 value in Field 1.

Scenario 1 Expected Results:

```
Field1   Field2
01       A
01       B
```

Scenario 2 Expected Results:

```
Field1   Field2
03       D
04       D
```

I think I will need to break this into 2 different SQL queries. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 'Scenario 1' AS scenario, 
  Field1 AS Field, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT Field2) AS Assignments 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY Field1 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Field2) > 1 
  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Scenario 2' AS scenario, 
  Field2 AS Field, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT Field1) AS Assignments 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY Field2 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Field1) > 1
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row scenario    Field   Assignments  
1   Scenario 1  01      A,B  
2   Scenario 2  D       03,04
```

Note: above solution allows you to run all in one query
Assumption here though is that both fields are of STRING data type. If this is not a case  - you just need to add CAST(... TO STRING) for respective field

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`/`not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.field1 = t.field1 and t2.field2 <> t.field2
             );
```

Use `not exists` for the second condition.